# "The remote host has closed the connection" when trying to "GET" JSON from rest API

Tags: c#, json, get, json.net

I'm trying to setup this rest API connection in my application. Using the RESTClient-extension for Firefox I have no problem to GET the required JSON from the rest API. Just by simply adding a content-type header and general header. Setup like this:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
cache-control: no-cache
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 16:42:10 GMT
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
request-context: appId=cid-v1:ad184906-400d-40d2-ba28-505dd7f0dd5c
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-firefox-spdy: h2
x-ms-client-tracking-id: 08586347691545143565364371309CU56
x-ms-correlation-id: d06da526-72ed-4608-9bef-6b4c32343090
x-ms-execution-location: westeurope
x-ms-ratelimit-burst-remaining-workflow-writes: 5624
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-workflow-download-contentsize: 402639066
x-ms-ratelimit-time-remaining-directapirequests: 37499071
x-ms-request-id: westeurope:d06da526-72ed-4608-9bef-6b4c32343090
x-ms-tracking-id: d06da526-72ed-4608-9bef-6b4c32343090
x-ms-trigger-history-name: 08586347691545143565364371309CU56
x-ms-workflow-id: dc37d2006c9543ffbc0f31db4a1983ab
x-ms-workflow-name: get-locationdata
x-ms-workflow-run-id: 08586347691545143565364371309CU56
x-ms-workflow-system-id: /locations/westeurope/scaleunits/prod-68/workflows/dc37d2006c9543ffbc0f31db4a1983ab
x-ms-workflow-version: 08586419277868524373
```

Not having such luck from within my application. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible, but keep getting "The remote host has closed the connection" when executing.

I've tried numerous approaches on setting up the connection with the API. But keep getting the same error.

```
        try
        {
            var webreq = WebRequest.Create(URL);
            webreq.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;
            webreq.Method = "GET";
            webreq.ContentType = "application/json";
            webreq.Headers["Subscription-Key"] = "9a719d58dacc4cc5b829c8bc71355e";

            try
            {
                using (var webresp = webreq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    //Process response
                    using (var webresp_1 = new StreamReader(webresp))
                    {
                        var contributorAsJson = webresp_1.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                //Exception
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Exception
        }
```

I think there is some kind of default parameter not setup quite right. Only I have no idea which one it is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to rule out any oddities, have you tried making the GET request in [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/)?
As a side question...is this failing method "async", or called from an async method with a missing "await" possibly?

Comment: Edit: Just saw you have it working in Firefox, ignore the PostMan comment. If you could show the full method the code snippet above came from it may provide a clue.

Comment: Is your program accessing the site via HTTPS?  The strict-transport-security header could be the reason if you aren't.

Comment: @SimonWilson No, it's not an async method

Comment: @Duston I didn't pay any special attention to that apart from using the HTTPS URL. Any suggestions ony modifying the webrequest to ensure it uses HTTPS?

Comment: If you're using an https URL then I would think that would rule out my idea.